# Change Subdivision Surface (2.9)

Tags: subdivision-surface

if I add a subdivision modifier with CTRL+2 the cube changes the way I want it to. How can I now mark the individually created faces? Unfortunately only the group is possible.
In Version 2.83 it worked without problems.

[image: Subdivision surface]

[image: Subdivision surface wireframe]

Comment: What are you talking about? It worked exactly the same in prior versions - with the modifier not applied you cannot edit geometry generated by it, only the geometry that is used by it to generate the result.

Comment: Hello :). You can see all faces by unchecking *Optimal Display* in your modifier (it's enabled by default in 2.9). But to select the faces, you still need to apply the modifier.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed the apply button. It changed a little bit in Version 2.9 and i didnt find it. 
Now it worked!